# Non-shell command on region?

Tags: region, pipe

I know about `shell-command-on-region`.

Is there any way to pipe a region through a non-shell command? The `start-process` and `call-process` functions invoke executables directly, without using the shell. I'd like to avoid shell overhead when piping the contents of a region into an external command, as well.

Can this be done in emacs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not cross-post the same question to SO and emacs.SE. Choose one or the other. Thx.

Comment: What overhead do you perceive? What platform are you using? `shell-command-on-region` ends up calling `call-process-region` with the variable `shell-file-name` as the command.

Comment: Yes, I know that the shell-file-name program is used to invoke the command. If I invoke call-process with "/usr/bin/wc", the shell (for example, perhaps /bin/sh) is invoked, and then it goes ahead and calls /usr/bin/wc. The "overhead" I'm talking about is the invocation of /bin/sh. I want to be able to pipe directly into /usr/bin/wc from the buffer, without /bin/sh also being called. It appears that this is not possible in emacs, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: I stumbled upon `make-pipe-process`. I think i can use it to create a process for running an executable without using any shell, which can then accept input via `send-process`. That input could be the contents of a buffer. I will code up a proof-of-concept, and if it works, I'll post it here as an answer. Excelsior!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. It turns out that I can send input to a process invoked via `start-process`, and so I don't need to use `call-process` at all. Since `start-process` doesn't invoke the specified command via the shell, this solves my problem.

Here is a simplified example which shows how to do it ...

```
(let ((proc (start-process "procname" "buffname" "/path/to/executable" "arg0" "arg1")))
  (process-send-region proc (point-min) (point-max))
  (process-send-eof proc))
```